# print unicode character as string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting tyoed characters with pynput, then I want to retype it as string, e.g. "č" as "č" and not u'\u010d'
What am I doing wrong?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        moje = format(key.char)
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
    #print('{0} released'.format(key).encode('utf-8'))
    #print('{0} released'.format(key).encode('cp437'))
    a = format(key)
    a = a.encode('cp437')
    print a #<-- here are "bad" chars produced / especially decoding issues / it shows unicode string but I am not able to show it properly, or save it to file, it shows/saves u'\u010d' instead of č
#     import codecs
#     f = codecs.open("test", "w", "utf-8-sig")
#     #f = open('test', 'w')
#     f.write(a) #<-- here are "bad" chars produced / especially decoding issues / it shows unicode string but I am not able to show it properly, or save it to file, it shows/saves u'\u010d' instead of č
#     f.close()
#     f = file('test', 'r')
#     print f.read().decode('cp437')
#     print u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f'
    #print  u'não vou esqueçer mais de usar o u no começo' 
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until they are released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Can you indicate where the discrepancy is happening?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I added place of discrepancy

Comment: Use Python 3. Easy peasy.

Comment: @erip, probably I could. But I would like to solve it in python 2.7,too

Comment: You are printing the encoded bytes. Why do you expect to see a string? Print the string while it is still decoded.

Comment: Also, I should have asked first, what is `key`?

Comment: key is a typed character/button on keyboard. You are right,  encoding is the issue here.